# Div not stretching as it should

Tags: html, css

I got this layered kind of style going on on the website I'm building.

Previously it was like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer" style="width:70%" class="Center Pane0 PaneWrapper">
        <div class="Pane1">
            blah blah
        </div>

        <div class="Pane1">
            blah blah
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and all was well, mainContainer stretched its height to minimal amount required by the content inside. Then, I decided to add a sidebar like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer" style="width:70%" class="Center Pane0 PaneWrapper">
        <div style="width:80%;float:left">
            <div class="Pane1">
                blah blah
            </div>

            <div class="Pane1">
                blah blah
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="width:19%;float:left">
            <div class="Pane1">
                imaginary sidepanel
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and suddenly, the mainContainer height seems to be 0 (its only height comes from margin/padding values affecting it). Is this regular behavior? Somehow I remember it differently.

.Pane0 and .Pane1 are merely visual styles and don't affect positioning in any way, .PaneWrapper currently only adds padding:10px and .Center does margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto

Whats going on here?

Comment: Can you post your css, specific i think class="Center Pane0 PaneWrapper">

Comment: I painted the `mainConatiner` red. Is this what you expected to get? http://jsfiddle.net/0jktnqyg/4/

Comment: @Afsa yes, after I replaced float:left with display:inline-block it's now showing up correctly, thanks.

Comment: add code in jsfiddle for understand what are you want ?

Comment: @Singh He added floats and said `the mainContainer height seems to be 0` a *jsfiddle* is not needed.

Comment: ok. It's not problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the style of your `div` elements from `float:left` to `display:inline-block;` you prevent the parent element from collapsing.

```
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer" style="width:70%" class="Center Pane0 PaneWrapper">
    <div style="width:80%; display:inline-block;">
        <div class="Pane1">
            blah blah
        </div>

        <div class="Pane1">
            blah blah
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width:19%; display:inline-block;">
        <div class="Pane1">
            imaginary sidepanel
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0jktnqyg/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear your floats.
A nice way to do it is to use
 `overflow:auto;` for `#mainContainer`

or apply this class:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
  content:' ';
  display:table;
}
.clearfix:after{
  clear:both;
}
```

[Demo using **clearfix**](http://jsbin.com/veqiro/1/edit)
[Demo using **overflow**](http://jsbin.com/veqiro/2/edit)

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/